# How to make jsoncpp throw in this case?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I'm using jsoncpp on ubuntu 14.04. Installed with apt-get libjsoncpp-dev libjsoncpp0. I'm not sure what version of jsoncpp it is.

I had a typo in a key name (in C++) and it was really tricky to track down. Consider this example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Json::Reader reader(Json::Features::strictMode());
  Json::Value obj;

  std::string json = "{\"mykey\" : 42}";

  if (!reader.parse(json.c_str(), obj)) {
    std::cout << "JSON parse error" << std::endl;
  }
  const Json::Value& mykey1 = obj["mykey"];
  std::cout << "mykey1:" << mykey1.asInt() << std::endl;

  const Json::Value& mykey2 = obj["mykey_typo"];
  std::cout << "mykey2:" << mykey2.asInt() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'm getting this output:

```
mykey1:42
mykey2:0
```

The fact that an access to a non-existent key produces a value of 0 is scary to me. It means if there is a typo the program will just use zero instead of the correct value. I'd rather know there was a typo. Is there a way to make jsoncpp throw or what is the recommended approach here?

I can write a helper that calls isMember and then does the lookup, but was wondering if the library itself has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like by design the behavior of jsoncpp `asInt` returns 0 when the value is null. Perhaps do a null check before using the value?

Take a look at line 721 in the [source](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/blob/master/src/lib_json/json_value.cpp#L721).

Comment: What surprised me is jsoncpp will throw on a parse error. But it doesn't throw on a "access error". You can ask for non-existent keys, even from a null object, and there is no error. And null returns 0 numeric value and no error. The solution I guess is just use isNull and isMember explicitly.

Comment: It appears that this could be an attempt by the jsoncpp devs to emulate the behavior of [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/).

However, I'm not sure if accessing a nonexistent key in a JsonValue object increases the size.

Comment: Hmmm, yeah I'm tempted to make a wrapper object that does throw, but then I'm wondering if I'm swimming upstream and should just accept the library's approach that nothing throws. At any rate for example this is not an error: root["bogus1"]["bogus2"]["bogus3"].asInt() just returns 0.